# how to rewrite single URL using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to rewrite only 1 specific URL, to display to visitors specific content: I tried something like, this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} example.com/test/2_5/page.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ example.com/tt.html [R,L]
```

I need to rewrite all requests to:

```
http://example.com/test/2_5/page.html
```

to

```
http://example.com/tt.html
```

how to do this?

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Redirect /test/2_5/page.html /tt.html
```

Ok, mod_rewrite

```
RewriteRule ^/test/2_5/page.html /tt.html [L]
```

Remove first / if using .htaccess in the site's root folder, not the .conf file. And, typically, the final url should be the full one, with http:// and domain, but this one will work too. If you want to do everything by the rules then

```
RewriteRule ^/test/2_5/page\.html$ http://example.com/tt.html [L]
```

Comment: I want to rewrite not redirect

Comment: @mwafi why?? result is the same